# What can I do about a laptop stolen out of luggage in transit?

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, security

My uncle was coming to visit me in Ecuador and bringing a laptop for me. It was in his checked bags, but somewhere between Panama City, Panama, and Quito, Ecuador, it was stolen out of his luggage.  The bag was not stolen, only the laptop.  Obviously he should have had a lock on it, but he didn't.  Is there any recourse for this?  The airline's policy is that a written report needed to be filed within 7 days (which we didn't do), and his credit card travel insurance excludes computers, software and cell phones. Even if it didn’t, the language skirts the issue of theft from baggage.

Is there really no recourse for something like this?

Comment: Why didn't you report it to the airline? Did you have travel insurance?

Comment: We tried calling the airline multiple times, but could never get through to a human.  By the time he was returning and back at the airport, it had been more than a week.  And the travel insurance he had was through his credit card, which had the exclusions I've listed above (computers, software and cell phones).

Comment: Which airline was it?

Comment: The airline was Copa.

Comment: You may be able to explain to the airline that it took you more than a week to get through. All that said, they are probably going to need some proof you actually had a laptop in Panama City- it would be very easy for customers to claim missing merchandise otherwise

Comment: I am sorry about your loss.

Comment: Ya, the proof part is the kicker.  It was a used laptop, and even if it wasn't, a receipt wouldn't indicate that it was in the luggage.  Lost luggage is one thing (mistake), but I feel like the airlines/airports should be accountable for their employees stealing things.  I suppose that's just the risk we take when we give our bags over to strangers.

Comment: Decent airports have cameras all the way once the luggage is handled by an employees till it reaches the hand of the passenger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kicker is the delay, once you pass the airlines reporting deadline, the chances for compensation drop to basically zero.  Too easy for folks to start claiming all sorts of non-existant items.  Personally I would have been persistent with calls or perhaps gone back to the airport to report the theft.

At this point your best bet is to write a polite letter explaining the situation, include copies of the ticket, boarding passes and purchase receipt.  You might get lucky.

But I suppose at this point the two of you have learned the number one rule about baggage when flying .... put nothing of value in checked bags.

Comment: So if you don't put anything of value in checked bags, where do you put it? In your hand luggage? Or should you not be carrying any at all?

Comment: @MoltenIce - you ALWAYS carry your valuables in your hand luggage, laptops, phones, passport, money, jewelry, etc.  You never put it in checked bags. That is Air Travel 101.

Comment: @Tom http://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2017/3/21/15000424/laptop-ban-us-airports-muslim

Comment: @JuniorDev - I think are all aware that stupid trumpism, but still does change the rule of thumb not to check valuables.