# My sister's laptop was gone when she gate-checked her bag. What can she do?

Tags: airport-security, security, refunds, delta-air-lines

My sister was visiting for the holidays and had to gate check her bag on the return trip. Once she got her bag back, her MacBook Air and charger were gone. What recourse does she have to get the laptop returned or a refund to buy another one?

We already checked Find My Mac, but the laptop shows as offline and no location info is given.

Comment: Contact the airline immediately.

Comment: Who were you flying with? From where? To where?

Comment: @JoErNanO It was a SAN -> MEM Delta flight. The airline has been contacted but I've been reading horror stories of how long it takes to get the issue resolved. Any tips on how to expedite?

Comment: I would also contact the police at those airports.

Comment: Too late for this to help, but if a loss is covered by insurance, the insurance company will pursue recovery—and they have the resources to get the attention of people who think they can ignore you and me.  Even so, I never check a laptop because of the abuse I've seen bags subjected to.  See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35027/what-can-i-do-about-a-laptop-stolen-out-of-luggage-in-transit?rq=1

Comment: @WGroleau Gate checking is rather different. It has much, much less handling by staff, and isn't always optional.

Comment: And when they insisted I gate-check a fairly small bag, I took my laptop out of it first.  Then from the "jetway," I watched a guy, instead of sliding the bag onto the belt through the hole (that was apparently designed for that purpose), pick it up over the rail and drop it onto the belt (waist high).

Answer (score 11):

There are a few things you can do:

1. Contact the airline.  The sooner you contact them, the better.  They usually will be happy to help you to get your computer back.
2. Contact the police.  They probably won't help, but if it was stolen, they'd be happy to investigate for you.
3. If you have insurance, contact them.  Even if they can't get the laptop back, you may have a reimbursement plan.